# Mouse Clicks on VMWare Fusion on MacBook Pro Ubuntu 18

Tags: mouse, vmware-fusion

Running Ubuntu 18.04 on VMWare Fusion 10.1.2 on a fully up to date Macbook Pro.  Ubuntu installs and runs, and mouse moves on screen; but does not respond to mouse clicks. Neither the trackpad on Mac nor a Bluetooth mouse works.  Mouse on Ubuntu 16.04 on same VMWare and Macbook works fine.  I have preference to make 18.04 work correctly, of course. I've found VMWare's suggstion to change to mouse.vusb.startConnected="FALSE" but that made no difference.

Any advice here as to how to make mouse clicks work

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on 8.5.10 after updating to Mac OS Mojave.

Try this:

1. Go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy**
2. Switch to the **Privacy** tab
3. In the left column, select **Accessibility**
4. Look in the right window pane.
5. If VMWare Fusion is listed but not checked, add the checkmark.
6. If VMWare Fusion is not listed, add it by selecting the "+" sign and navigating to it.
7. Once added, restart VMWare Fusion.

Good luck.